# Github actions canceling job on kill command

Tags: python, linux, github, process, github-actions

I am running a script in the background on linux using:

```
python3 bot.py command &
```

and during github actions deployment I am using:

```
kill $(pgrep -fi bot.py)
```

To cancel the previous job before starting one again.

However, when I do that... it cancels the github actions job with the following error:

```
Process exited with status 137 from signal KILL
```

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `kill <pid>` is a `SIGKILL` [signal](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) & `python` throws `137` exit code (128 + 9).

As you are doing this manually (not because of a system resource crunch), you can put a `trap` to check the `137` exit code & decide your next actions.

```
#!/bin/bash

## catch the exit code & apply logic accordingly
function finish() {
  # Your cleanup code here
  rv=$?
  echo "the error code received is $rv"
  if [ $rv -eq 137 ];
  then
    echo "It's a manual kill, attempting another run or whatever"
  elif [ $rv -eq 0 ];
  then
    echo "Exited smoothly"
  else
    echo "Non 0 & 137 exit codes"
    exit $rv
  fi
}

pgrep -fi bot.py
if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
  echo "Killing the previous process"
  kill -9 $(pgrep -fi bot.py)
else
  echo "No previous process exists."
fi
trap finish EXIT
```